# GoLang Scraper. How to scrape dynamically generated links on a website?

Tags: go, web, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape product video links (which are generated dynamically by another web service. The location is under the product images on the left side). You can check following link,
https://www.tokopedia.com/chocoapple/ready-stock-bnib-iphone-128gb-7-plus-jet-black-garansi-apple-1-tahun-10?src=topads
The google chrome "inspect element" shows the div tag. But The same tag is not present in the page source.
How to do it? I am looking into goQuery to implement the task but not sure will it work or not. I am not a web developer so please consider giving suggestions if my question description is not specific.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tag is not in the source, then GoQuery will not work. GoQuery is for parsing HTML source using a jQuery-like API.

You need to first process the webpage with a headless WebKit like phantomjs, [chromeless](https://github.com/graphcool/chromeless), or [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer). Each of these tools will allow you to process all the Javascript on the webpage before processing it. This way, the AJAX for rendering the video you are interest in will be processed and the source will be updated. You can then download the corresponding source which should have the div in it.

Comment: in the nodejs world it worth to note you can also use nitghmarejs https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare

Comment: @schollz Processing webpage with headless WebKit, is it the standard way? Also, will it work on large scale in terms of performance?

Comment: @yogesh_desai As far as I know, it is the standard way. Headless webkits leverage browsers to do the rendering and I don't know another way to do that. As for performance scaling, you might look into chromeless which might let you scale via AWS Lambda

Comment: performance is a goal, not a metric. Not sure how we can help about that as there is not so many solution available afaik. go is good at concurrency which in such case is proven useful to reach a goal of performance.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to evaluate the page like a browser does. As schollz answered it, this is possible via so called headless browser (browsers usable via the cli or an api, which does not show their gui).

In go world there is chromedp

https://github.com/knq/chromedp

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7pWCg94sKw

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely check it out and give it a try. Also, please my comment on schollz's answer and provide more details.

Comment: To evaluate, means do I need to load the page through chromedp? How will I get updated source of the page? Which functions from chromedp are useful for me? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the next tag `<img class="thumbnail-img horizontal" src="//i.ytimg.com/vi/oKR2fh09Nic/mqdefault.jpg">`. As you see src contain ID "oKR2fh09Nic". This is need path https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKR2fh09Nic

Also, you can use `http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id= oKR2fh09Nic` for loading video information.

Example here https://github.com/kkdai/youtube/blob/master/youtube.go

Comment: Will it work for multiple videos? As the link, I have shared has 4 videos. Also, when you say find the next tag what does that mean?

Comment: The tag you mentioned <img class is visible when I do "inspect element" but not in "page source". Please let me know how to find it?